# How to properly check if an input is only binary number?

Tags: java, binary, runtime-error

Could someone tell me why this bit of code keeps telling me Number Format Exception  and not print my error message when I'm trying to convert from a binary number to a decimal?`

```
public static void readAndConvertBinaryValue()
{
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean valid = false;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a binary value containing up to 16"
                + " digits: ");
        bAction = kbd.nextLine();
        int result = bAction.compareTo(BINARY_NUM);
        if (result > 1 || result < -9 || bAction.length() > 16)
        {
            System.out.print("Error: Invalid binary value."
                    + "\nTry again.\nPress Enter to continue ...");
            kbd.nextLine();
        } else
        {
            char value;
            int charlim = 0;
            value = bAction.charAt(charlim);
            if (value == '1' || value == '0')
            {
                binary = Integer.parseInt(bAction, 2);
                valid = true;
            } else
            {

                System.out.print("Error: Invalid binary value."
                        + "\nTrya again.\nPress Enter to continue ...");
                kbd.nextLine();
            }
        }
    } while (!valid);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you check all the digits, not just the first one. I also suggest you check there is less than 33 or this will also give you a NumberFormatException.  A simple approach is not not check and instead catch the NumebrFormatException if it occurs.

Comment: I just added the code

Comment: After you get an error you discard the next line read.  I suggest you step through your code in your debugger to get a better understanding of what your code is doing?

Comment: How would i check all the digits? @PeterLawrey

Comment: @midknight you can use a regex or you can use a loop.  I suggest writing a method to contain the check.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not too familiar with regex

Comment: @midknight have you heard of google? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions:

```
boolean isABinNumber = bAction.matches("^[01]+$");
```

matches is defined in the String class and returns true if and only if the string matches the regular expression provided. The regular expression above (^[01]+$) covers all strings that from beginning (^) to end ($) is a sequence of one or more (+) 0 or 1s '[01]'.

If you are not familiar with regular expressions there is plenty of information on the web (e.g. [a tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html))

Comment: Or `matches("[01]{1,32}")`

Comment: I don't fully understand that sorry i'm still a novice programmer

Comment: @PeterLawrey since he is checking for a maximum length of 16 the 32bit limit is irrelevant.

Comment: @midknight Changed the answer to make more informative. Basically you can use the snipplet above for the section of the code that you use to check whether the value is a binary.

Comment: so i'd basically run that in an if statement huh?

Comment: @midknight yeah it would be your if (value =='1' || value == '0') .

Comment: @midknight if you need then the actually binary value the you can use Integer.parseInt(bAction,2) with confidence that it won't cause an exception and that is going to be a positive value; also since you already check of the length to be 16 or less you know that is going to fit in an 'int' variable.

Comment: @Valentin Ruano ohh now i see what you ment thank you it worked:)

Answer (score 1):

This all seems too complicated, just use Integer.parseInt() and catch the NumberFormatException if it occurs. You can then check the value is within the desired range.

```
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("\nEnter a binary value containing up to 16" + " digits: ");
String bAction = kbd.nextLine();
try {
    int binary = Integer.parseInt(bAction, 2);
    if (binary >= (1 << 16)) {
        System.err.println("Binary value out of range");
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.print("Error: Invalid binary value.");
}
```

Comment: You might not want to discard the line input after an error.

Comment: Following @PeterLawrey comment, perhaps the catch should set valid to false and the error message is show outside the try-catch based on the value in valid.

Comment: valid is already false, there is little point in setting it again.. I've only amended the code in the original problem, not invented new requirements...

Comment: You can refactor this so you don't need a `valid` flag. btw you can drop the line `kbd.nextLine();` and the "Press Enter to continue"  Also if the number is out of range, you won't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CheckBinary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        String binaryNumber = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        String binaryPattern = "(1*0*)*";   

        if (Pattern.compile(binaryPattern).matcher(binaryNumber).matches()) {
            System.out.println("Binary");         
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Binary");
        }        
    }

}
```